# Failed to read dockerfile in Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, airflow

I need to create a Docker image from command line but its results in error when i do:

**docker build -t airflow-basic .**

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount488297868/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

or when i do:

**docker build .**

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount116574587/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

**What can i do?**

**My DockerFile**

```
    # Base Image
FROM python:3.7-slim
LABEL maintainer="Gizelly"

# Arguments that can be set with docker build
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.12
ARG AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow

# Export the environment variable AIRFLOW_HOME where airflow will be installed
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Install dependencies and tools
RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get upgrade -yqq && \
    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \ 
    wget \
    libczmq-dev \
    curl \
    libssl-dev \
    git \
    inetutils-telnet \
    bind9utils freetds-dev \
    libkrb5-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libffi-dev libpq-dev \
    freetds-bin build-essential \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    apt-utils \
    rsync \
    zip \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    vim \
    locales \
    && apt-get clean

COPY ./requirements-python3.7.txt /requirements-python3.7.txt

# Upgrade pip
# Create airflow user 
# Install apache airflow with subpackages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_HOME} airflow && \
    pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,kubernetes,docker]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} --constraint /requirements-python3.8.txt

# Copy the entrypoint.sh from host to container (at path AIRFLOW_HOME)
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh

# Set the entrypoint.sh file to be executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Set the owner of the files in AIRFLOW_HOME to the user airflow
RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Set the username to use
USER airflow

# Set workdir (it's like a cd inside the container)
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Create the dags folder which will contain the DAGs
RUN mkdir dags

# Expose ports (just to indicate that this container needs to map port)
EXPOSE 8080

# Execute the entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]


****PS C:\Users\gizel\Documents\airflow-materials\airflow-materials\airflow-section-2> dir****
  


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        28/10/2020     14:21                docs
-a----        29/10/2020     19:59           1787 dockerfile
-a----        28/10/2020     14:21            208 entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Share your docker file

Comment: @Ashok I pasted my CLI commands that I used

Comment: Do you have a file named Dockerfile in that directory? No extension, case sensitive. Show the output of ls or dir.

Comment: @BMitch I updated my question with the content of the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is misnamed. The filename is case sensitive, so rename `dockerfile` to `Dockerfile`. Uppercase D, no extension.

Comment: It Worked Perfect!